# 404 Encountered Loading Legacy (v2.8) PrintTemplate in ArcGIS JS API

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

I've created a simple page which implements the PrintWidget and PrintTemplate functionality

Building this small example using version 3.11 of the ArcGIS API works absolutely fine, however when using version 2.8 (current version I'm working with) PrintTemplate seems to cause a 404 error. Having traced the error it seems unable to find http://serverapi.arcgisonline.com/jsapi/arcgis/2.8/js/esri/tasks/PrintTemplate.xd.js

Running the same file using v3.11 again I can see that it looks for http://js.arcgis.com/3.11/esri/tasks/PrintTemplate.js and this works fine.

It seems at some point from 2.6-3.11 - both the format of the file and it's location have changed.

I have checked and rechecked the JS API for PrintTemplate - it does state that it was implemented in v2.6 so it does not seem like a versioning problem. I have tried to find examples using the legacy/non AMD implementations of PrintTemplate but thus far have been unsuccessful.

Given that I may not be able to upgrade to v3.11 without significant work, is there any solution for this?

Hopefully this is a coherent enough explanation of my problem - again I have only just stepped into the world of ArcGIS so this may prove to be an easy fix.

I'm very new to ArcGIS so forgive me if this is a rudimentary problem.

Comment: Which version of ArcGIS Server are you using? Is your Print Service set to asynchronous or synchronous. Typically you set it to synchronous. Can you post some code?

Comment: Its ArcGIS Server v10.2 and the PrintService is synchronous. The code itself is absolutely the simplest example you could think of - At this point it seemed to be more viable to simply upgrade to a newer version of the API and solve the versioning problems rather than trying to get functionality out of an older version.

Thanks for the help regardless =)